# Create two associated dropdown lists in HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to create two associated dropdown lists in HTML using javascript. It was fun but I have faced a barrier. Hope someone can give a hint here. Keep it simple, the case is the second dropdown list's options are based on the selected value of first dropdown list. Hence, the second dropdown list's options will be variant with the selected value of first dropdown list.

My idea was to create a javascript function listens to the onclick action of first dropdown list and record the selected value. Then, the second dropbown list can retrieve back the stored value and display corresponding options based on it. However, I was not sure about how to retrieve back the selected value cause it belongs to the javascript function of first dropdown list.

Comment: The problem has been solved thousands of times before. Look in the net for linked selects or double combo.

Comment: Thanks a lot, epascarello. I'm a new bird of Javascript so that I don't know the key word to search. It helps a lot and I have completed the function. It works well. Thanks again.